# Shorten imported variable exports in Go / Golang?

Tags: go

if I have

```
// types.go

type S string

func (s *S) Lower() *S {
    *s = S(strings.ToLower(string(*s)))
    return s
}
```

`

```
// in another file

import "u/types"

func main() {
    s := types.S("asdf")
    if s == "asdf" {
        s.Lower()
    }
}
```

1. Is there a way to shorten types.S("asdf") to just S("asdf")?
2. Is there a way to lowercase method calls from other files? e.g. s.Lower() => s.lower()?

Comment: 1. If all your `main()` code was in the same package as `types` you wouldn't need the package name. (You could write types.Main and just call that from your main package).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not recommended for most cases but you can do `import . "u/types"` and all then skip the types prefix. `.` will import all the public symbols into your package for you allowing you to call them as if they were local to your package.

Answer (score 0):

1. Not as long as that type is in a different package from where you're using it, without using dot-imports.
2. Yes, if the other file is still in the same package. Otherwise, no, because then the function won't be exported (visible to other packages). This is Go convention.